# В Midnight Commander обычный «+» и "-" на клавиатуре срабатывает как select/deselect

Tags: linux, fedora, mc

В Midnight Commander обычный  <kbd>+</kbd> и <kbd>-</kbd> на клавиатуре срабатывает как select/deselect. Система Fedora 28. Хотя то же на виртуальной машине у Centos и Ubuntu последней. Mc версии 4.8.19. Кто то переборол?

Comment: эмм... а что перебарывать то?

Comment: как чего? Чтобы плюс/минус на в верхней клавиатуре не выдавали окна с select/deselect, как на дополнительной цифровой справа. Когда набираешь команду с ключём, допустим -r, сделать это невозможно при открытых панелях. Только после Ctrl+O

Comment: у меня выдаёт это окно только если в строке ввода пусто; соответственно никаких подобных неудобств нет. [`mc --version`](http://paste.debian.net/1030655/).

Comment: До upgrade то же было нормально и только в пустой строке. После обновления c 27 до 28 версии, и повышения версии mc до 4.8.19 получил такую беду.

Comment: в ванильном 4.8.19 (из git'а) у меня проблема тоже не воспроизводится...

Comment: Потрите конфигурацию в *~/.config/...* или где там её ваша версия читает.

Comment: А вообще, конечно, правильно не пользоваться mc совсем.

Comment: спасибо. Рыдаю у вас на плече

Answer (score 1):

Ввести плюс в Midnight Commander в командной строке при включенных панелях можно предварительно нажав Ctrl+q и затем нажать "+" или "-" в официальном [FAQ](https://midnight-commander.org/wiki/doc/faq#a2.5HowcanIaddtheplussignonthecommandline) есть такой вопрос.

Но лично мне удобнее на момент ввода команды просто отключить панели (Ctrl+o) ввести все что я хочу и включить их назад той же комбинацией клавиш.